# MegaRAID possibly failing

Tags: megaraid

We are trying to see if a disk has failed or if it is the card. Researched on this forum and found this -> [Drive is failing but LSI MegaRAID controller does not detect it](https://serverfault.com/questions/485147/drive-is-failing-but-lsi-megaraid-controller-does-not-detect-it)

However, we are getting that error for all slots.

```
==========
Device ID: 9
Enclosure Index: 252
Slot Number: 0
CDB Length: 6
CDB Data:
001a 0008 00c8 0000 00ff 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 Sense Length: 18
Sense Data:
0070 0000 0005 0000 0000 0000 0000 000a 0000 0000 0000 0000 0024 0000 0000     0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 

seqNum: 0x00005a5a
Seconds since last reboot: 25
Code: 0x00000071
Class: 0
Locale: 0x02
Event Description: Unexpected sense: PD 0a(e0xfc/s2) Path 4433221101000000,     CDB: 1a 08 c8 00 ff 00, Sense: 5/24/00
Event Data:
```

In addition, I have checked Windows Event viewer and getting these errors:

```
The default transaction resource manager on volume \\?Volume(etc...) encountered a non-retryable error and could not start. The data contains the error code.
```

And this:

Warning - Source Disk

```
The IO operation at logical block address 0x0 for Disk 2 (PDO name: \Device\00000005f) was retired.
```